# WKWebView: how to know if something was blocked by setContentBlocker

Tags: objective-c, swift, wkwebview

Depending on the rules as outlined [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/creating_a_content_blocker#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016265), images, scripts, or css + more could be blocked, which could render the page useless. I would love to know if some element was blocked on the WKWebView, in which case I would display some kind of floating banner indicating as such to the user. Is it possible to know this without parsing the json myself and re-implementing the rules?